# weblogic 11g deployment error , loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME"

Tags: jersey, weblogic, weblogic11g

i add my project the maven jersey rest services dependency. It's working well, but if I try to deploy  weblogic 11g i got this error

[HTTP:101216]Servlet: "jersey-serlvet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "PstnIptalv1.war". java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the referring class,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have prefer-web-inf in you weblogic.xml file   Otherwise it might conflict with a class weblogic is providing for you

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```