# Weblogic 12c deployment error , loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME"

Tags: java, weblogic

I am getting error while deploying war file in weblogic server and this is legacy application ,we used ant scripts for debug this application can some one hemp me please why we are getting this issue?

### Error

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "JerseyRESTService" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "Sample.war".
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, er, have different Class objects for that type
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:473)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:186)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:348)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:96)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1984)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1958)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1877)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3173)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1529)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:488)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:573)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:327)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1531)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:488)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, er, have different Class objects for that type
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have prefer-web-inf in you weblogic.xml file Otherwise it might conflict with a class weblogic is providing for you

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

Original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725593/weblogic-11g-deployment-error-loader-constraint-violation-when-resolving-fiel)